# ejabberd form another device

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I have a question regarding ejabberd. I have installed and configure and ejabberd on my Mac OS. When I connect from my IOS simulation on the same computer I am able to open a stream although the stream gives and error message but I am able to send and receive info to and from server. If I try the IOS simulation on a different computer I can't open a stream. How Can I fix that problem. My question is how can I open a stream from another computer that does not have ejabberd configured but have an XMPP on the client?

Thanks

Comment: Which framework your using ??

Comment: Robbie Hanson framework Objective -C

Comment: your server device should be accessible from client device and should accept connections on port 5222 which is used for c2s.